# When establishing a relative symbolic link, what does the "different versioned object base" error mean?

Tags: clearcase, symlink

I am attempting to create a relative symbolic link via clearcase as so:
`ct ln ../../../some/actual/file.txt file.txt`

However, I get the following error:

```
cleartool: Error: Source "../../../some/actual/file.txt" and destination "file.txt" are in different versioned object bases.
```

In context of clearcase relative symbolic links, what does "different versioned object bases" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First "in different versioned object bases" refers to [VOBs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/about_vob.htm), two different permanent data repositories in which you store files, directories, and metadata.

A [`cleartool ln`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ru/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ln.htm) without the `-slink` option would create a **hardlink**, that is  an additional name for an existing element.

And:

- For VOB hard links, each pname must specify an existing element that is not a VOB symbolic link and **that resides in the same VOB as the link being created**.
- For VOB symbolic links, pname need not reside in the same VOB as the link to it, nor be an existing element.